# How to get data from 2 related tables in the same controller in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to get data from 2 DB tables that are related. Departments and Functions: Each Department has multiple Functions.

I want to show all data in an accordion on the same page.

Until now, the code works like this: 
Declare the variable departments in the controller, and in view, in the foreach loop, I have called the Functions model in a variable.

Controller:

```
public function index(){
        //Data variable declarations
        $data['page_title'] = "Departments and Functions";
        $data['page_subtitle'] = "choose an occupation for the list of users assigned";

        //Data variable declaration - from models
        $data['departments'] = $this->Department->get_all('departments');

        $this->load->view('layouts/header');
        $this->load->view('layouts/title', $data);
        $this->load->view('layouts/aside');
        $this->load->view('departments/index', $data);
        $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
    }
```

Here I want to add the Function->get_by_department_id() method. How to get the ID  dynamically?

The occupation model methond:

```
public function get_by_fk($table = 'occupations', $fk = "department_id" , $fk_value=$department->department_id){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($table);
        $this->db->where($fk, $fk_value);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $result = $query->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a left join

```
function get_departments_and_functions() {
    $sql = 'SELECT `deptartments`.*, `functions`.* 
            FROM `departments` LEFT JOIN `functions` 
                  ON `functions`.`deptartments_id` = `departments`.`id`';
    return $this->db->query($sql)->result();
}
```

You could also query the departments and then foreach over the departments and query to get the functions. Then you would manually build the result set.